# Sorted function in python

Tags: python, sorting

I have written a program which must sort the following:

```
unsorted_list=[['le', 5], ['aab', 4], ['aaa', 5]]
```

to:

```
[['aaa', 5], ['le', 5], ['aab', 4]]
```

It should be sorted by number. If the numbers are the same then it should sort alphabetical.
I have the following code:

```
def sortItem(lista):
    ''' func for sort by item'''
    return lista[1]
sorted(unsorted_list, key=sortItem, reverse=True)
```

Unfortunately, it does not return string alphabetical. 
Any suggestion how to do it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since `x[1]` is an integer, you can sort it from maximum to minimum simply by negating it:

```
sorted(unsorted_list, key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0]))
```

The tuples created in `key` will be sorted according to the first element (`-x[1]`), then by second element (`x[0]`). This corresponds exactly to your logic:

*"So, it means than it is sorted by number but if numbers are the same the sort will be alphabetical."*

Comment: And the reason this works is because sequences are compared lexicographically

Answer (score 6):

```
In [2]: l = [['le', 5], ['aab', 4], ['aaa', 5]]

In [3]: sorted(l, key=lambda (x,y):(-y,x))
Out[3]: [['aaa', 5], ['le', 5], ['aab', 4]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone is not familiar with the lambda function, here is how to break this down by defining your own function from the scratch -

```
unsorted_list=[['le', 5], ['aab', 4], ['aaa', 5]]
def num_and_alpha(tuple):
    return (-tuple[1], tuple[0])

print sorted(unsorted_list, key=num_and_alpha)
```